# Simple Table with dplyr on Sequence Data

Tags: r, count, dplyr, summary

I would like to make a simple **table** with

```
dplyr
```

and

```
summarise
```

But I can't really figure out how ... (Even though it should be quite simple).

I have a matrix of sequences. 
When I simply tabulate

```
 table(dta)
```

I have the result I want.

```
 dta
            acquaintance                        alone                        child                    notnotnot                      nuclear 
                       1                            2                           17                           19                          131 
 nuclear and     acquaintance  nuclear and    acquaintance    nuclear and  acquaintance     nuclear and acquaintance                      partner 
                       1                            1                            1                           35                            2
```

However, 
I can't figure out how to do the same with **summarise**

Any suggestion ?

```
 dta =   structure(c("nuclear", "nuclear", "child", "child", "child", 
"acquaintance", "nuclear and acquaintance", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"notnotnot", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "child", "child", 
"child", "alone", "nuclear and acquaintance", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"notnotnot", "nuclear", "nuclear", "child", "child", "child", 
"child", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"notnotnot", "nuclear", "nuclear", "child", "child", "child", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"notnotnot", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "child", "child", 
 "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"notnotnot", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"notnotnot", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"notnotnot", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"notnotnot", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"notnotnot", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"notnotnot", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"notnotnot", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"partner", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
 "partner", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
 "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", "nuclear and  acquaintance", 
 "notnotnot", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and     acquaintance", 
 "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
 "notnotnot", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and    acquaintance", 
 "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "notnotnot", "nuclear", 
  "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
 "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "notnotnot", "nuclear", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "notnotnot", "nuclear", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "notnotnot", "nuclear", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "child", "nuclear", "notnotnot", "nuclear", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear and acquaintance", 
"nuclear", "nuclear", "child", "alone", "notnotnot", "nuclear"
), .Dim = c(10L, 21L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), c("12:10", "12:20", "12:30", 
"12:40", "12:50", "13:00", "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", 
"13:50", "14:00", "14:10", "14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50", 
"15:00", "15:10", "15:20", "15:30")))
```

Comment: yeah you are right, I misread the data-format, because of the structured format :D, reading the answer now my suggestion makes no sense, but at least I was right on with the data.frame part ^^

Comment: You can do inline code formatting with backticks, like ``"I would like to use `dplyr` with `summarise` here"``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to convert your data to a `data.frame` to use `dplyr` and then you can easily get your desired output:

```
require(dplyr)
# ungrouped
data_frame(var = c(dta)) %>% 
  group_by_("var") %>% 
  summarise(n())
##                             var n()
## 1                  acquaintance   1
## 2                         alone   2
## 3                         child  17
## 4                     notnotnot  19
## 5                       nuclear 131
## 6  nuclear and     acquaintance   1
## 7   nuclear and    acquaintance   1
## 8     nuclear and  acquaintance   1
## 9      nuclear and acquaintance  35
## 10                      partner   2
```

If you want to do this for each column seperately, you can use `tidyr` to first gather the result and then spread it again.

```
require(tidyr)
# grouped
dta %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  gather %>% 
  group_by(key, value) %>% 
  summarise(N = n()) %>% 
  spread(key, N)
##                           value 12:10 12:20 12:30 12:40 12:50 13:00 13:10 13:20 13:30 13:40 13:50 14:00 14:10
## 1                  acquaintance     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
## 2                         alone    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
## 3                         child     3     3     4     3     2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
## 4                     notnotnot     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1    NA    NA
## 5                       nuclear     3     3     3     4     5     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7
## 6  nuclear and     acquaintance    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
## 7   nuclear and    acquaintance    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
## 8     nuclear and  acquaintance    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
## 9      nuclear and acquaintance     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
## 10                      partner    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     1
## Variables not shown: 14:20 (int), 14:30 (int), 14:40 (int), 14:50 (int), 15:00 (int), 15:10 (int), 15:20 (int), 
## 15:30 (int)
```

Comment: excuse me, where does the *key* comes from ?

Comment: the key comes from the gathering. If you look at `?tidyr::gather`, you see that you can specify the name yourself. The default name will be `"key"`

Comment: hum ... ok because the default value when I run the code is *variable* and *value*

Comment: using `tidyr_0.2.0` or newer, the default should be `key`.