# R - dplyr summary of activities by variables

Tags: r, sequence, dplyr, summary

I am experiencing some problems with a summary solution [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941737/simple-table-with-dplyr-on-sequence-data).

I am simply trying to `summarise` sequence data I have by **activities** and by two variables **(gender and children)**.

Here is my sequence dataset

```
dta = structure(c("d nuclear", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
        "e nuclear and acquaintance", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
        "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "j work study sleep", "c child", "d nuclear", 
        "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
        "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", 
        "j work study sleep", "c child", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
        "e nuclear and acquaintance", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
        "d nuclear", "c child", "j work study sleep", "c child", "d nuclear", 
        "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
        "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", "d nuclear", "c child", 
        "j work study sleep", "c child", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
        "e nuclear and acquaintance", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
        "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "j work study sleep", "c child", "d nuclear", 
        "a alone", "e nuclear and acquaintance", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
        "b partner", "b partner", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "j work study sleep", 
        "c child", "d nuclear", "a alone", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
        "e nuclear and acquaintance", "b partner", "b partner", "d nuclear", 
        "d nuclear", "j work study sleep", "c child", "d nuclear", "a alone", 
        "e nuclear and acquaintance", "d nuclear", "b partner", "b partner", 
        "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "i True Missing", "c child", "d nuclear", 
        "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "b partner", "b partner", 
        "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "i True Missing", "c child", "d nuclear", 
        "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "b partner", "b partner", 
        "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "j work study sleep", "c child", "d nuclear", 
        "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "b partner", "b partner", 
        "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "j work study sleep", "c child"), .Dim = 10:11, .Dimnames = list(
          NULL, c("12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", "13:00", 
                  "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50")))
```

The solution [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941737/simple-table-with-dplyr-on-sequence-data) works perfectly fine when I only `summarise` activities

```
require(dplyr)

data_frame(var = c(dta)) %>% 
  group_by_("var") %>% 
  summarise( smn = n() * 10, min = smn / 20)
```

However, what I need now to do is to group_by children and gender.

```
dta = as.data.frame(dta)
dta$children <- rep(x = c(1,0), times = 5)
dta$gender <- c( rep('H', 5), rep('F', 5) )
dta$idno <- c( 1:10 ) # personal identifier
```

I was thinking of a solution like this but it doesn't work

```
data_frame(var = c(dta)) %>% 
  group_by_("var", "children", "gender") %>% 
  summarise( smn = n() * 10, min = smn / 20)
```

Do you have any idea why this is incorrect ?

My original dataset is organised like this `dta` with alread the variables **children**, **gender** and **idno**.

So the output I would like is similiar to a regular `summarise` but I need to desegregate by gender and children - so a basic `summarise` :

```
                         var smn  min
                 a alone  30  1.5
               b partner 120  6.0
                 c child 130  6.5
               d nuclear 510 25.5
e nuclear and acquaintance 200 10.0
          i True Missing  20  1.0
      j work study sleep  90  4.5
```

Dividing by 20 `/20` is wrong here, each category should be divided by

```
table(dta$children, dta$gender)

    F H
  0 3 2
  1 2 3
```

Is there a way to divide by the right number of categories directly and not *by hand* ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the expected output. By doing `c(dta)`, you are converting the 'var' in a list of 13 elements

Comment: You don't have a column named `var`, what do you mean by that? You're also recreating the data frame with new column names when you run `data_frame(var = c(dta))`. Show the expected output and your solution is probably very straightforward.

Comment: perhaps `dta1 <- data.frame(Var=c(dta) , children=rep(x = c(1,0), times = 5), gender=c( rep('H', 5), rep('F', 5) )); dta1 %>% group_by(Var, children, gender) %>% summarise( smn = n() * 10, min = smn / 20)`

Comment: Your problem lies on using `data_frame(var = c(dta))` after `dta` is already a data.frame with your grouping columns. Change the order like proposed by akrun and it should work.

Comment: @Moix I think I made a mistake. `dta1 %>% group_by(children, gender) %>% mutate(n1= n()) %>% group_by(Var,add=TRUE)  %>% summarise(smn = n()*10, min= smn/n1[1L])`

Comment: The expected output is just a regular `summarise` output, with `var` as activities variables and then a **sum** and **min**. But this time I want to include also the two other variables. @akrun - so what would be your correct last answer ? It seems to work

Comment: what about `melting` first `dta = melt(dta, id = c("idno", "isex", "children"))
dta = arrange(dta, idno)?`

Comment: Try `dta1 %>% group_by(Var, children, gender) %>% summarise( smn = n() * 10, min = smn / 20) %>% group_by(Var) %>% summarise(smn=sum(smn), min=sum(min))`

Comment: @akrun - I will play with it and see what I get. Thanks for your help and effort !

Comment: It gives me the expected output you showed.

Comment: I still have some trouble with the Var transformation because my dataset originally contains gender and children. So I have problems when I transforms Var with the two variables. Too complicated ...